# Tricky Encryption Algorithm Design

Tags: algorithm, math, encryption, binary, logic

> Bob and Alice each have a bit string they want to keep private.  They each want to know what the logical AND of their two bit strings would be without telling the other or anyone else their actual bit strings... how can they do this? Keep in mind that even once they both hold the AND of their two bit strings, they should still not be able to calculate the other person's string exactly (unless of course one of their strings was all 1s).

I know that I have seen something similar before in some sort of key system/voting system but I couldn't remember the details.  It has to be something like make a private random key, xor it and use that somehow... but I couldn't work out the details. Any clever encryption people out there?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? Do they think it belongs in a different Stack Exchange or something?

Comment: Yes; this isn't really a programming question (at least not the way it's currently framed).

Comment: ok which one should it go to... 'math' or 'theoretical computer science'... also I have seen many algorithm questions show up on stack overflow and isn't 'programmers' the place for pure programming questions?

Comment: @hackartist You might try http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ for this

Comment: Ok I asked it over on crypto, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are looking for **[homomorphic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption)** systems, in which it's possible to do computation on encrypted values without ever exposing what those encrypted values are.  This encompasses a far more general set of problems than simply computing bitwise AND.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks... how would I go about it for this specific problem though... what would each party send to the other?